# Redirection best practices/frameworks while merging two websites

Tags: .net, iis, redirect

We are in the process of merging two websites A and B. Both are .NET applications. Currently we have various situations where A has to redirect to B for pages, and there are situations where B redirects to A for some other pages.

We are currently having a mapping file in xml, and handling the redirection scenarios. On top of this, we have to share the states(session,cache) as well.

Is there any best practice or redirection framework for this kind of requirements?